# Is it possible to always use the latest nuget version including preview?

Tags: nuget

I know that to always use a latest nuget package in my client project, I need to do things such as:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="MyServerNugetPackage" Version="2.*" />
```

So this will force my project to take the latest version 2 nuget package. As I am both the consumer and creator of the nuget package, the QA team wants that certain branch of my client project, I should consume the **latest preview** version of the nuget package (So they can test the preview functions in the nuget package before other teams consume them).

As my knowledge goes, "2.*" will return the latest stable version of nuget package and I am not really aware if it is possible to get latest preview version. Can it be done?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. Use this

`<PackageReference Include="MyServerNugetPackage" Version="*-*" />`

### Note

Useful commands to verify the resolutions are

```
dotnet restore
dotnet list package
```